# Why does `make` think these are invalid options?

Tags: makefile, chocolatey

I get the following error when building [zedboard](https://github.com/ucb-bar/fpga-zynq/tree/master/zedboard):

```
redacted@redacted C:\dev\fpga-zynq\zedboard
$ make vivado
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/make/tools/bin/make -C C:/dev/fpga-zynq/rocket-chip/firrtl SBT="java -Xmx2G -Xss8M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar C:/dev/fpga-zynq/rocket-chip/sbt-launch.jar" root_dir=C:/dev/fpga-zynq/rocket-chip/firrtl build-scala
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- X
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- x
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- 2
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- G
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- X
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- 8
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- M
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- X
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- X
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- :
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- M
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- a
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- x
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- P
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- z
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- =
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- 2
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- 5
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- 6
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\bin\make: invalid option -- M
make: the `-j' option requires a positive integral argument
Usage: make [options] [target] ...
Options:
  -b, -m                      Ignored for compatibility.
  -B, --always-make           Unconditionally make all targets.
  -C DIRECTORY, --directory=DIRECTORY
                              Change to DIRECTORY before doing anything.
  -d                          Print lots of debugging information.
  --debug[=FLAGS]             Print various types of debugging information.
  -e, --environment-overrides
                              Environment variables override makefiles.
  -f FILE, --file=FILE, --makefile=FILE
                              Read FILE as a makefile.
  -h, --help                  Print this message and exit.
  -i, --ignore-errors         Ignore errors from commands.
  -I DIRECTORY, --include-dir=DIRECTORY
                              Search DIRECTORY for included makefiles.
  -j [N], --jobs[=N]          Allow N jobs at once; infinite jobs with no arg.
  -k, --keep-going            Keep going when some targets can't be made.
  -l [N], --load-average[=N], --max-load[=N]
                              Don't start multiple jobs unless load is below N.
  -L, --check-symlink-times   Use the latest mtime between symlinks and target.
  -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon
                              Don't actually run any commands; just print them.
  -o FILE, --old-file=FILE, --assume-old=FILE
                              Consider FILE to be very old and don't remake it.
  -p, --print-data-base       Print make's internal database.
  -q, --question              Run no commands; exit status says if up to date.
  -r, --no-builtin-rules      Disable the built-in implicit rules.
  -R, --no-builtin-variables  Disable the built-in variable settings.
  -s, --silent, --quiet       Don't echo commands.
  -S, --no-keep-going, --stop
                              Turns off -k.
  -t, --touch                 Touch targets instead of remaking them.
  -v, --version               Print the version number of make and exit.
  -w, --print-directory       Print the current directory.
  --no-print-directory        Turn off -w, even if it was turned on implicitly.
  -W FILE, --what-if=FILE, --new-file=FILE, --assume-new=FILE
                              Consider FILE to be infinitely new.
  --warn-undefined-variables  Warn when an undefined variable is referenced.

This program built for i386-pc-mingw32
Report bugs to <bug-make@gnu.org>
make: *** [C:/dev/fpga-zynq/rocket-chip/firrtl/utils/bin/firrtl.jar] Error 2
```

I am using `make` from [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/make).

```
redacted@redacted C:\dev\fpga-zynq\zedboard
$ where make
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\make.exe
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe
C:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin\make.exe
```

I've tried reordering variables in my PATH, installing things my msys2 and mingw, but to no avail. I'm using Windows 10 with Cygwin, but the tools I'm using here are Windows-native. I'm not sure why it would be throwing the invalid option errors, it's a bit mystifying to me.

Comment: Which version of make is that ? You can know it by typing `make --version`. I don't know this chocolate thing but I think the make command is totally valid. It seems that the double quotes are simply ignored, then make interprets what should be in the SBT var as if it was its own parameters. Anyway try to install the most recent GNU Make ( you can find one already built here : https://nuwen.net/mingw.html )

Comment: Something is eating up your quotes. From the error message, `make` tries to parse the value of `SBT` as its own commandline. Maybe try to execute the make in an [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/) shell?